# PrimeNG Table column sorting doesn't work

Tags: angular7, primeng-turbotable

I have created an Angular application using PrimeNG Table. I've checked the PrimeNG Documentation here (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/sort). The problem is that my table is not sorting. The sorting icons are showing up, and when I press any of them, the animation changes, but the data is not being sorted.

Here is my code for the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DownloadService } from '../services/download/download.service';
import { SelectItem, MultiSelectModule } from "primeng/primeng";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-downloads',
  templateUrl: './downloads.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./downloads.component.css'],
  providers: [DownloadService]
})

export class DownloadsComponent implements OnInit {

  downloadData: any[] = [];
  cols: any[];
  columnOptions: SelectItem[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private data: DownloadService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.getData();
    }, 5000);
  }

  getData() {
    this.data.GetDownloads().subscribe(data => {
      this.downloadData = data;
    });
  }
}
```

and the code for component.html

```
<p-table [value]="downloadData" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" sortMode="multiple" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" [rowHover]="true">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;" [pSortableColumn]="'Logger Name'">Logger Name
        <p-sortIcon [field]="'Logger Name'"></p-sortIcon>
      </th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" [pSortableColumn]="'Progress'">Progress
        <p-sortIcon [field]="'Progress'"></p-sortIcon>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-download>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">{{ download.logger.name }}</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <p-progressBar [value]="download.progress"></p-progressBar>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was missing the #dt [columns]="cols" directives in the p-table tag. Populating the cols field and adding the directives solved the problem.